auto generating thumbnails from images with pillow and bytesIO i django
I've been trying to automatically generate thumbnails from images that I upload to the admin console in Django (I'm using drf). I want to be able to generate thumbnails for images that I upload when creating new objects.
def get_event_thumb(self):
    if self.event_thumb:
        return "http://127.0.0.1:8000" + self.event_thumb.url
    else:
        if self.event_img:
            self.event_thumb = self.make_thumbnail(self.event_img)
            self.save()
            return "http://127.0.0.1:8000" + self.event_thumb.url
        else:
            ''
        

        
def get_event_img(self):
    if self.event_img:
        return "http://127.0.0.1:8000" + self.event_img.url
    else:
        ''



def make_thumbnail(self, image, size=(300, 200)):
    img = Image.open(image)
    img.convert('RGB')
    img.thumbnail(size)
    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(thumb_io, 'JPEG', quality=85)

    thumbnail = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)

    return thumbnail

This is what I've written in the models.py file. It's not showing me any errors at the moment, just not generating the thumbnails.
